# Равномерная сортировка по убыванию от точки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с координатами `point`, как сделать запрос, чтобы самые ближе лежащие точки отсортировались вверх, а самые далекие вниз?

Допустим я делаю что-то типо `order by NextToThisPoint(0, 0)`

И мне первым выдает строки с координатами `1, 3` и `5, 12`, а какой-то `123, 553` упадет вниз списка

Comment: как хранятся координаты? на X и Y по столбцу или в одном столбце через запятую?...... если координаты у одной точки 1,3 а у другой 3,1  то кто должен быть главнее?  или сортировка ведется именно по длине? x²+y²?

Comment: пока на ум приходит только полный расчет расстояния от исходной точки до каждой точки из таблицы (через временную таблицу или массив). но этот вариант годен для небольшого количества данных.

Comment: посмотрите это решение, но там все реализовано через процедуры, что чем-то напоминает мое решение, только переложенное на плечи mysql: http://www.pvsm.ru/mysql/33928

Comment: Долгота и широта хранится в  `point`

Comment: Данных много, почти миллион

Comment: Если сортировать "в лоб" (как вам ответили), то это приведет к filesort. Возможно, стоит использовать геометрические индексы https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для плоскости.
x0,y0 - координаты точки, относительно которой сортируется.

```
SELECT x, y, SQRT((x-x0)*(x-x0)+(y-y0)*(y-y0)) AS distance FROM table ORDER BY distance
```

Для глобуса.
lat0, lng0 - географические координаты точки.

```
SELECT 
    lat, 
    lng,
    ACOS(
        SIN(PI()*lat/180.0)*SIN(PI()*lat0/180.0)
        +COS(PI()*lat/180.0)*COS(PI()*lat0/180.0)
        *COS(PI()*lng0/180.0-PI()*lng/180.0)
    )*6371 AS Kilometers
FROM table
ORDER BY kilometers
```

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать запрос по координатам, что не так?

```SELECT ST_X(coordinates) as lat, ST_Y(coordinates) as lng,
SQRT((lat-60)*(lat-60)+(lng-30)*(lng-30)) AS distance   
FROM `table`
ORDER BY distance```

Comment: Это способ для расстояния на плоскости с ортогональными осями. Для latitude/longitude формула дистанции совсем другая, довольно адского вида. Попробую поискать, где-то было записано...

Comment: @Fangog добавил

Comment: Ругается на ` #1054 - Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'` https://hastebin.com/ligilowuki.sql

(lat0 и lng0 заменить не забыл)

Comment: @Fangog ну у вас же такого поля и нет. Судя по предыдущему вашему комментарию вместо lat надо подставить `ST_X(coordinates)`. И lng тоже поменять не забудьте